# Is there's a regulator or redressal mechanism for Broker Firms

Tags: india, stock-markets, online-brokerage, regulation

I have account with zerodha. I have made a huge loss of 80000 rupees because of zerodha's system failure.

I have raised this with Zerodha, they are neither replying nor do I see any effort to recover my loss. Is their a regulatory or Independent redressal mechanism that can help.

Comment: A much better-worded question (which hopefully has given you the answer you need), but I _think_, in future, you would have been better editing the original question rather than asking a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Brokers are regulated by [Securities and Exchange Board of India](http://www.sebi.gov.in/about.html). Please read the [FAQ on what types of complaints](http://www.sebi.gov.in/sebi_data/faqfiles/jan-2017/1485859549392.pdf) can be raised. The website for registering the complaints is [SCORE](https://scores.gov.in/scores/Welcome.html). Alternatively you are also send a postal complaint to any of the SEBI branches nearest to you.